# Looking to find the sum in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sum

I keep getting `NA` for the code below to find the sum of vector in R without using `sum()`:

```
total <- 0
for ()) {
    add = gg[n] + gg[n+1]
    total = total + add
}
```

Comment: `for (n in seq_along(gg)) {
  total = total + gg[n]
}
`

Answer (score 2):

Your getting a NA because gg[n+1] does not exist when last step (length(gg)) : so it finally adds NA to your sum.

Use `for (n in (1:(length(gg)-1)) )` instead

(and tip to debug : print the contents of your variables at each steps using print() - launch code below to see your issue :

```
 total <- 0
 for (n in (1:length(gg)) ) {
   print(paste("n: ",n))
   print(paste("gg for n : ",gg[n], "and n+1: ",gg[n+1]))

  add = gg[n] + gg[n+1]
  print(paste("add when loop = ", n, ":", add))
  total = total + add
  print(total)
}
total
```